# How to subtract year from date

Tags: date, oracle

I have date in `CHAR YYYYMM` format, I want to subtract one year from date and convert it back to `CHAR FORMAT`

> Example

```
YYYYMM '199211'
```

> Result:

```
'199111'
```

Comment: For what? SQL Server or Oracle? Or Both?

Comment: @Berend For Oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert to a number, subtract 100, convert back to char:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_NUMBER('199211') - 100)
FROM dual;
```